# Android change background xml of shape doesn't function

Tags: android

I have this background for a progressBar:

> circle_prorgress_foreground.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="@dimen/inner_radius_progress"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="@dimen/thickness_progress"
            android:useLevel="true">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:endColor="@color/accentColor"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How you can see it's a gradient with start and endcolor different. If progress is 100 it doesn't seems very good and aesthetic, so i would switch to another XML with start and end color fixed.

> circle_progress_foreground_100

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="@dimen/inner_radius_progress"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="@dimen/thickness_progress"
            android:useLevel="true">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/accentColor"
                android:endColor="@color/accentColor"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is the code's piece where I switch the XML:

```
[...]

    int progress = (int) Math.round(100-(day_to_next_event*3.57141));
                if (progress>100){
                    progress = 100;
                }

                Log.d("PROGRESS_IS", "progress is " + progress);

                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", progress);
                animation.setDuration(500); // 0.5 second
                animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animation.start();

                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress==100){
                    mProgress.setProgress(0);
                    mProgress.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_progress_foreground_100));
                    mProgress.setProgress(100);
                }

[...]
```

My Log.D says that progress is 100, but xml doesn't switch at all (but APP functions as expected). Simply, I have the first one circle_progress_foreground rendered, with the gradient.

I saw others questions and I did understand that I cannot change color directly from Java, if shape is custom. If this is possible, i would like to change directly via Java, instead of creating 2 XML.

Thank you

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong method.

Right method is:

```
    if (progress==100){
        mProgress.setProgress(0);
        mProgress.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_progress_foreground_100));
        mProgress.setProgress(100);
    }
```